# Is there any way to control uncontrollable or deviating thoughts according to Shastras?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, smriti, reference-request, parashara-smriti

I want to know if our Shastras mention how to control uncontrollable or deviating thoughts especially during prayer,Japa or Sadhna?

Comment: https://youtu.be/zCT3wcoZ9ds

Comment: Just keep patience and continue practicing. You'd win over it soon. That's what I have read.

Comment: @user2225190 thanks but it would be better if there is some shastric reference.

Comment: @sbharti these thoughts overcome me once I am doing japa or sadhna. I don't know how to control them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is a symptom of not following Saadhna or Dhyaan routine properly. I came across this issue in [Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/complete_works.htm) earlier and would  like to suggest you to read in detail [Chapter 1.4.21: PRACTICAL RELIGION: BREATHING AND MEDITATION](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/lectures_and_discourses/practical_religion_breathing_and_meditation.htm) on how to practice meditation with best results.

In [Shrimadbhagvadgita : Chapter 6 : Dhyaan yog](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=6&field_nsutra_value=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&choose=1), Bhagwan Krishna talks in detail about credentials of a Yogi and how to become one. I will share few shlokas here for reference, but would advise to go through complete chapter for proper understanding.

Step 1: Place and Posture

> शुचौ देशे प्रतिष्ठाप्य स्थिरमासनमात्मनः। नात्युच्छ्रितं नातिनीचं चैलाजिनकुशोत्तरम्।।6.11।।
>
> In a clean spot, having established a firm seat of his own, neither too high nor too low, made of a cloth, a skin and Kusa-grass, one over the other.
>
> तत्रैकाग्रं मनः कृत्वा यतचित्तेन्द्रियक्रियः। उपविश्यासने
> युञ्ज्याद्योगमात्मविशुद्धये।।6.12।।
>
> There, having made the mind one-pointed, with the actions of the mind
> and the senses controlled, let him, seated on the seat, practise Yoga
> for the purification of the self.
>
> समं कायशिरोग्रीवं धारयन्नचलं स्थिरः। संप्रेक्ष्य नासिकाग्रं स्वं
> दिशश्चानवलोकयन्।।6.13।।
>
> Let him firmly hold his body, head and neck erect and still, gazing at
> the tip of his nose, without looking around.
>
> प्रशान्तात्मा विगतभीर्ब्रह्मचारिव्रते स्थितः। मनः संयम्य मच्चित्तो
> युक्त आसीत मत्परः।।6.14।।
>
> Serene-minded, fearless, firm in the vow of a Brahmachari, having
> controlled the mind, thinking of Me and balanced in mind, let him sit,
> having Me as his supreme goal.

Step 2 : Balanced food, Balanced sleep, Balanced exercise

> नात्यश्नतस्तु योगोऽस्ति न चैकान्तमनश्नतः। न चातिस्वप्नशीलस्य जाग्रतो
> नैव चार्जुन।।6.16।।
>
> Verily Yoga is not possible for him who eats too much, nor for him who
> does not eat at all, nor for him who sleeps too much, nor for him who
> is (always) awake, O Arjuna.
>
> युक्ताहारविहारस्य युक्तचेष्टस्य कर्मसु। युक्तस्वप्नावबोधस्य योगो भवति
> दुःखहा।।6.17।।
>
> Yoga becomes the destroyer of pain for him who is moderate in eating
> and recreation (such as walking, etc.), who is moderate in exertion in
> actions, who is moderate in sleep and wakefulness.

Step 3 : Determination, Focus

> तं विद्याद् दुःखसंयोगवियोगं योगसंज्ञितम्।
> स निश्चयेन योक्तव्यो योगोऽनिर्विण्णचेतसा।।6.23।।
>
> Let that be known by the name of Yoga, the severance from union with pain. This Yoga should be practised with determination and with an undesponding mind.
>
> सङ्कल्पप्रभवान्कामांस्त्यक्त्वा सर्वानशेषतः।
> मनसैवेन्द्रियग्रामं विनियम्य समन्ततः।।6.24।।
>
> 6.24 Abandoning without reserve all desires born of Sankalpa (thought and imagination) and completely restraining the whole group of the
> senses by the mind from all sides.
>
> शनैः शनैरुपरमेद् बुद्ध्या धृतिगृहीतया।
> आत्मसंस्थं मनः कृत्वा न किञ्चिदपि चिन्तयेत्।।6.25।।
>
> 6.25 Little by little let him attain to ietude by the intellect held firmly; having made the mind establish itself in the Self, let him not
> think of anything.
>
> यतो यतो निश्चरति मनश्चञ्चलमस्थिरम्।
> ततस्ततो नियम्यैतदात्मन्येव वशं नयेत्।।6.26।।
>
> 6.26 From whatever cause the restless and unsteady mind wanders away, from that let him restrain it and bring it under the control of the
> Self alone.

Step 4 : Continuous Practice

> युञ्जन्नेवं सदाऽऽत्मानं योगी विगतकल्मषः। सुखेन ब्रह्मसंस्पर्शमत्यन्तं
> सुखमश्नुते।।6.28।।
>
> 6.28 The Yogi, always engaging the mind thus (in the practice of Yoga), freed from sins, easily enjoys the Infinite Bliss of contact
> with Brahman (the Eternal).

Arjun asks pretty much the same question you have

> योऽयं योगस्त्वया प्रोक्तः साम्येन मधुसूदन।
> एतस्याहं न पश्यामि चञ्चलत्वात् स्थितिं स्थिराम्।।6.33।।
> 6.33 Arjuna said This Yoga of eanimity taught by Thee, O Krishna, I do not see its steady continuance, because of the restlessness (of the mind).
>
> चञ्चलं हि मनः कृष्ण प्रमाथि बलवद्दृढम्।
> तस्याहं निग्रहं मन्ये वायोरिव सुदुष्करम्।।6.34।।
> 6.34 The mind verily is restless, turbulent, strong and unyielding, O Krishna: I deem it as difficult to control it as to control the wind.

Bhagwan Krishna re-iterates that continuous practice and commitment is required.

> असंशयं महाबाहो मनो दुर्निग्रहं चलं।
> अभ्यासेन तु कौन्तेय वैराग्येण च गृह्यते।।6.35।।
> 6.35 The Blessed Lord said Undoubtedly, O mighty-armed Arjuna, the mind is difficult to control and restless; but by practice and by dispassion it may be restrained.